# Unable to install libsvm from pip on linux

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, libsvm, sidekit

I am trying to run sidekit for that I need to install libsvm, and using pip I am getting the following error.

Tried: **pip install libsvm**, **sudo pip install libsvm** and
**sudo -H pip install libsvm**

---

```
adit@adit-HP-ProBook-440-G2:~$ **python**

Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

**import sidekit**

Import theano

WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): The cuda backend is deprecated and will be removed in the next release (v0.10).  Please switch to the gpuarray backend. 
You can get more information about how to switch at this URL:

 https://github.com/Theano/Theano/wiki/Converting-to-the-new-gpu-back-end%28gpuarray%29

ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): nvcc compiler not found on $PATH. Check your nvcc installation and try again.

WARNING:root:WARNNG: libsvm is not installed, please refer to the documentation if you intend to use SVM classifiers

adit@adit-HP-ProBook-440-G2:~$ **sudo pip install libsvm**

The directory '/home/adit/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/adit/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting libsvm
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 512, in _prepare_file
    finder, self.upgrade, require_hashes)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 273, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 442, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 400, in find_all_candidates for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 545, in_get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 648, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 757, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",

File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 378, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 46, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)

File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 376, in send
    timeout=timeout

File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 610, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])

File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 228, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use pip with  sudo?

Comment: Tried **pip install libsvm**, still getting a long paragraph of errors.

Comment: Please edit the question to include those

Answer (score 2):

libsvm is a C++ package and has a python wrapper. You first need to install the libsvm package itself.

```
sudo apt install libsvm3
```

And then install the python wrapper.

```
sudo apt install python-libsvm
```

If you are on ubuntu you may use synaptic package manager. It would make life lot easier.

EDIT : For older version of OS, if you use apt-get, use apt-get instead of apt.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

sudo pip install libsvm

or

sudo -H pip install libsvm

Comment: I think It is not a packages in python. Try this apt-cache search libsvm

Answer (score 0):

apt-cache search libsvm

sudo apt-get install libsvm*

*= one of name from search

Comment: Thanks!  **sudo apt-get install python-libsvm** worked fine. Now new set of errors are occurring though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to download and compile for yourself, then look for a libsvm.so.2 file and put in the folder sidekit/libsvm/

Comment: this doesnt look like an answer, just a comment.